# How can I prove that for any control system root locus plot starts from poles of OLTF and ends at zeroes of OLTF?

Tags: control, control-system, transfer-function, pole-zeroplot, root-locus

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3e3AX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

G(s)H(s)=N/D

T(s)=KN/(D+KN)

Proof:
[image]]
**But**

**For K=0 T=0**

**For K=infinity T=infinity**

then how can K=0 {condition where forward path gain becomes zero} be considered as condition where the poles of T(s) will be equal to poles of G(s)H(s) when the transfer function has become equal to zero how can any value of s make the transfer function peak to infinity { condition of poles } and how can characteristic equation be defined for case  when T(s)=0

Comment: What work have you done so far?

Comment: As previous posts - you've done no research. This is page 1 of the chapter on root locus, and easily found on the web.

Comment: @Chu plz  see edits

Comment: Is T(s)=KN/(N+KD) supposed to be the CLTF? If so, it's wrong.

Comment: You are going into too many unnecessary details. Root locus is to check the stability of a **closed loop** system. If \$k=0\$ there is no closed loop (no forward path) and no question of stability. So, yes we would care about the root locus only in the limit as \$k \rightarrow 0\$ and not when it is \$0\$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CLTF is: \$ T(s)=\frac{KN(s)}{D(s)+KN(s)}\$, and the characteristic equation (CE) is:

\$\small D(s)+KN(s)=0\$

As \$\small K\$ goes from zero to infinity, the roots of the CE trace out the root locus, which is the path of the closed loop poles in the complex s-plane.

For the start and end points of the locus, we let \$\small K=0\$ and \$\small K\rightarrow\infty\$, respectively, as follows:

When \$\small K=0\$, the CE is: \$\small D(s)=0\$, and the roots are thus the poles of the open loop TF.

When \$\small K\rightarrow \infty\$, \$\small KD(s)>>N(s)\$, and the CE is: \$\small KN(s)=0\$; hence \$\small N(s)=0\$, and the roots are the zeroes of the open loop TF.

Comment: You mean K never becomes equal to zero but tend to zero because other wise "how can K=0 {condition where forward path gain becomes zero} be considered as condition where the poles of T(s) will be equal to poles of G(s)H(s) when the transfer function has become equal to zero how can any value of s make the transfer function peak to infinity { condition of poles } and how can characteristic equation be defined for case when T(s)=0" {mentioned in question}

Comment: K=0 is a mathematical convenience. The root locus is defined on the characteristic equation, not on the CLTF. We let K tend to infinity because infinity is not a number.

Comment: How can a TF peak to infinity .... try 1/(s+1) with s=-1

Comment: Why can't characteristic equation be defined when K=0? It's defined as N(s)+KD(s)=0, so we have N(s)=0 when K=0 --- what's the problem with that? e.g. N(s)=(s+a)=0 gives s=-a. Think before you type.

Comment: Ok consider loop gain = K(s+1)/(s+2)s

Comment: then CLTF=K(s+1)/{(s+2)s+K(s+1)}

Comment: So what's your point?

Comment: At K=0 what will be CLTF look like ......0/(s+2)s      Now 0/finite=0 isn't it so naturally there is no way CLTF will peak to infinity is there.Only way the CLTF not equal to 0 is at s=0,-2 but it will still not be infinity so,CLTF is not peaking so why should I consider them as poles for K=0.

Comment: Why are you pre-occupied with K=0? this is only the starting point of the root locus, which is the paths of the roots in the complex plane. There is no implication that we operate the system with K=0 , that's clearly nonsense. You are misinterpreting the process. We select the value of K using information gleaned from  the root locus.

Comment: At K=0 we have D(s)=0. D(s) is the denominator of the open loop TF, therefore D(s)=0 are the poles of the open loop TF, so the root locus starts (K=0) at the open loop poles.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96616/discussion-between-sunita-gupta-and-chu).